# Can I setup "Automatic Billing" with a button that has some kind of transaction/session ID

Tags: paypal

...that then gets passed back to me with an IPN hit once the initiation is successful?

I'm finding both PayPal's glossary terms (eg. "Automatic Billing") and documentation somewhat fragmented. Where's the best place to find answers to this kind of question?

Answer (score 0):

OK, well it's quite easy to get something into the IPN - just put the id into "item_name". However, the user return URL seems to be a bit trickier...